# Changing color of button when clicked in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, colors

Searching through the site I found how to change a buttons color in WPF when button is pressed. What I am not sure about is how to make it to where it would change back when pressed again. this is the code I have:

```
<Button Margin="917,631,480.8,144.4" Background="Transparent" x:Name="blackCounter6" >
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="50"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Unpressed:
[image: Unpressed]

Pressed:
[image: Pressed]

The first image shows the button before its pressed, the second after. Im trying to revert it back when pressed again. It is a control that sits behind the image, I used a button because I know how to make them round and fit right into place like it is. I also have C# script that can be used to achieve this. I assume I add some sort of function to revert it back to its original state maybe?

Answer (score 1):

"it would change back when pressed again"?
I think you prefer a Checkbox instead of button.
you can add a trigger for Checkbox style as blow.

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
```

If you need Storyboard.Then the trigger IsChecked=False is unnecessary.
you can add <Trigger.ExitActions> after  <Trigger.EnterActions>.
In addtion, <Trigger.ExitActions> and  <Trigger.EnterActions> should be used as couple usually.

Code for CheckBox.
Especially,about the Template of Checkbox,you can access it from xaml view-> Document Outline->find Checkbox control->Right Click->Edit Template->Edit a copy->OK.you will get the full Template Code of CheckBox.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="excontent" Margin="5" Panel.ZIndex="9" Fill="Blue" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="content" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                      </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I explained properly, that is a good idea I had not considered using a checkbox, but I am also not sure if I can make it round and also fit precisely what it is im doing. I don't know if I can add images to comments so I might have to edit the post but I took screenshots of the program

Comment: I totally see what you mean with the <Trigger.Enter/ExitActions> thing too actually

Comment: I saw it.I confirm you need Checkbox/ToggleButton other than Button.If you have to choose Button, you need import a boolean property/dependecyproperty for this Button.

Comment: Wait for a moment,I am working around some codes

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to define a style and use the triggers that manage the various states.

```
<Button Margin="917,631,480.8,144.4" Background="Transparent" x:Name="blackCounter6" >
<Button.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryApplicationColorBrush}"/> //Set your background
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ApplicationForegroundColorBrush}"/> //Set your default foregraound color 
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/> //Set your border brush color
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontNormal}"/> //Set your desired font
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}"/> //Set your font size
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBackground}"/> //Set your background when the button is pressed 
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBorderBrush}" /> //Set your BorderBrush when the button is pressed 
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMouseOverBorderBrush}" />  /Set your BorderBrush when the mouse is over
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>  //Set your background when the button is disabled
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" /> //Set your BorderBrush when the button is disabled
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```